# Select tag change event without user interference in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a small challenge here. I have 3 cascading drop down lists, `category`, `subcategory`, `subsubcategory`.The user selects a value from `category` list then related values show up in `subcategory` and when the user `CHANGES`the value from `subcategory` related values on `subsubcategory` will show up. My problem is, I want to fire the `change` event on `subcategory` list without user selecting a new value! I want to simply show related values in `subsubcategory` when the user selects a value in `CATEGORY` NOT `SUBCATEGORY` list! 
here is the code:-

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#category').change(function(){
    var category_id = $(this).val();    
    //alert(category_id);
        $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"/search_subcat",

           data:{'category_id':category_id},
           dataType: 'json',
           success:function(res){                  
                //console.log(res); 
                $("#subcategory").empty();
                //$("#subcategory").append('<option value="0">Select</option>');

                 $.each(res, function(index, element) {
                $("#subcategory").append('<option value="'+element.id+'">'+element.subcategory+'</option>');
            })

            },error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
               $("#subcategory").empty();
             }
           });
});
   $('#subcategory').change(function(){
    var subcategory_id = $(this).val();
    var category_id = $('#category').val();    
    //alert(category_id);
        $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"/search_subsub",

           data:{'category_id':category_id, 'subcategory_id':subcategory_id},
           dataType: 'json',
           success:function(res){                  
                //console.log(res); 
                $("#subsubcategory").empty();
                //$("#subsubcategory").append('<option value="0">Select</option>');
                 $.each(res, function(index, element) {
                $("#subsubcategory").append('<option value="'+element.id+'">'+element.subsubcategory+'</option>');
            })

            },error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
               $("#subsubcategory").empty();
             }
           });

    });
```

It works perfect, all that I want to do is to simply fire `$('#subcategory').change` without user changing its value instead, I want it to fire when the user selects a `category` value.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calling `change()` with no arguments will trigger the event...or use `trigger()`

```
$('#subcategory').change()
```

Or

```
$('#subcategory').trigger('change')
```

Demo:

```js
$('#subcategory').on('change', function() {
  console.log('New value is ', this.value)
}).val(2).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="subcategory">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Full code for what? You asked how and this does what you ask. Also not exactly sure when you want to trigger it

Comment: I want the `subsubcategory` value to appear automatically because sometimes there is only one related `subcategory` for the selected `category` and that will not fire the change event since the select tag will have only `1 option`

Comment: OK... if there is only one add an empty one that has `value=""` and then set `<select>` value to the valid one and trigger change